# What I hope for is to V/Ving

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I'd like to know "what someone hopes for is" should be followed by a to-infinitive or a gerund:

> What Peter hopes for is to buy/buying a sports car.

Comment: If "hope" it's followed by a verb, it's always a to-infinitive. That's still true, even with this sentence structure

Answer (score 1):

I hope to buy a new car.
Peter hopes to buy a brand-new washing machine.
There in your example we need an infinitve which functions as object of the verb. As a result, (to buy) is correct.